# Store checked checkbox in gridview in database ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am able to retrieve out data from database to show which is Y and N using checkbox in gridview. However now i want to to able to store which checkbox is checked back into the database after editing.

What i did so far:

.aspx

```
    <asp:GridView ID="SiteGridView" runat="server" CssClass="datagrid" 
                  GridLines="Vertical" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Width="100%" 
                  AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
                  DataKeyNames="promoID"  OnRowCommand="GvPage_RowCommand" 
                  OnPageIndexChanging="GvPage_PageIndexChanging" 
                  OnSorting="GvPage_Sorting" 
                  OnRowDatabound="SiteGridView_RowDataBound"
                  OnRowEditing="SiteGridView_RowEditing">
      <Columns>       
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Default">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="process_flag" runat="server" 
              Checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("PROCESSED").ToString()) %>'
              Enable='<%# !bool.Parse(Eval("PROCESSED").ToString()) %>' />
          </ItemTemplate>
          <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
```

CodeBehind:

```
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * , CAST(CASE defaults WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS PROCESSED FROM Promotions"); 
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(); 
                DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
                da.SelectCommand = cmd; 

                // Save results of select statement into a datatable 
                da.Fill(dt);

                SiteGridView.DataSource = dt;
                SiteGridView.DataBind(); 

        protected void SiteGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                //check userrole & display accrodingly
                if (Session["ROLE"].ToString() != "SA")
                {
                    //ImageButton btnEdit = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete");
                    //btnEdit.Visible = false;
                    SiteGridView.Columns[4].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to save the checkbox state on every click? or just once after the user acts on several rows?

Comment: save the checkbox state on every click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Checkboxes do not trigger GridView RowCommand events.  It probably *can* be done with appropriate calls to `ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference()`, but thats a whole other level of complexity.  So, in order to act on a CheckBox click and handle events individually:

(NB: I've stripped out much of your coding to clarify my points.)

1. In your CheckBox set `AutoPostBack="true"`
2. Add a handler for `OnCheckedChanged`.
3. Make sure the DataKey contains the pk of the row you need to update with the CheckBox State

   ```
   // Simplified version of your markup
   <asp:GridView ID="SiteGridView" runat="server" 
                 DataKeyNames="promoID" 
                 OnRowDataBound="SiteGridView_RowDataBound">
     <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Default">
         <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="process_flag" runat="server" 
             Checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("PROCESSED").ToString()) %>'
             Enable='<%# !bool.Parse(Eval("PROCESSED").ToString()) %>'
             OnCheckedChanged="process_flag_CheckedChanged" />
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
   ```
4. In the `RowDataBound` event, find the CheckBox and add the Row Index as an attribute

   ```
   // Merge this with your `RowDataBound` event
   protected void SiteGridView_RowDataBound( object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e ) {
       if ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow ) {
           CheckBox cbx = ( CheckBox ) e.Row.FindControl( "CheckBox1" );
           cbx.Attributes[ "data-row-idx" ] = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
       }
   }
   ```
5. Handle the CheckChanged event:

   ```
   // Add this handler to your code
   protected void process_flag_CheckedChanged( object sender, EventArgs e ) 
   {
       CheckBox cbx = ( CheckBox ) sender;
       Int32 rowidx = Convert.ToInt32(cbx.Attributes["data-row-idx"]);
       Int32 pk = (Int32) GridView4.DataKeys[rowidx].Value;

       // simple way to see event arguments before actually touching the database
       GridView4.Caption = string.Format(
           "CheckChanged: Row {0}, State: {1}, RowPK: {2} ", rowidx , (cbx.Checked ? "Checked" : "Unchecked"), pk );

       // Save Data and rebind the gridview to reflect changes
       // Verify your parameters before attempting an actual update
       // YourDatabaseCallWithAppropriateParamaters( ... );
       GridView1.DataBind();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:
Checked='<%# Eval("PROCESSED")%>'

If so, what error messages have you gotten?

Answer (score 0):

First of all use a foreach loop to findout which rows are checked. Then store ID of those rows in a List.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in SiteGridView.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("process_flag") as CheckBox);
                if (chkRow.Checked)
                {
                    string ID = row.Cells[columnID].Text;
```

Comment: sorry but the columnID is? because my other column are boundfield connected to database.

Comment: Show me your SiteGridView_RowDataBound event

Comment: i paste the SiteGridView_RowDataBound event in codebehind

Comment: Pls share your save method to database